# How to define a PBI that has no perceived value to the user?

Tags: agile, scrum, user-stories

I need to add an item to our product backlog list that has no (perceived) value to the users.

**Context:** every week we need to parse and import a TXT file our system. Now the provider decided to change the format to XML, so we need to rewrite the parsing engine.

In the end the user won't see any benefit as he'll keep getting his new data, but we still have to do this to keep importing the data.

How to add an item like this to the product backlog list?

Comment: What is a PBI? Product Backlog Item?

Comment: @Dave Hillier precisely.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has no value to the user, but it has value to your company.

> As company X I want to be able to support the new XML format so that I can keep importing data from provider Y.

How does that sound like? Not all stories necessarily evolve around the end user.

Note: technical stories and technical improvement stories are *not* a good practice and they should avoided. Why? Because you can't prioritize them correctly as they have no estimable value.
The correct way to do tech stories is to include them in the definition of done. For example: decide that every new story played is only complete once database access is via Dapper and not L2S. This is a viable DoD definition and makes sure you can evolve your system appropriately.

Comment: It seems as if his change requires quite some rework, and should trigger thorough retests. Which item would you book this work against? The first item that you're taking up, regardless of what it is? How will you track whether all changes are tested properly?

Comment: I don't understand your comment: there is only one item in the question.

Comment: Yeh, but you answered that having a story for such a technical approvement are not good practice. You suggested adding them to the DOD. But don't you want significant changes like that tracable to a PBI, so you can follow them op accordingly?

Comment: I don't understand. You want to have a DoD which is achievable, therefore you necessarily need to limit the size of refactoring to something that is tractable. Everything that is included in the DoD is done *for each story*. E.g. if you add "story should be unit tested" then for each story you play, you add unit tests *for that story*. In case you need to do a lot of work in order to add unit tests to a single story, then you shouldn't have that DoD, you should add something achievable (e.g. it could be an integration test if your code is not tractable).

Comment: I was thinking the _user_  as a real person using the system, but in reality the user is in relation to the story, so it can be a real user, a system or any kind communication. This is not just a technical improvement as the TXT format will be discontinued, so we need to parse the new XML format.

Comment: This does have value to the PO, product and business and even the users.  If you do not import the data, then what impact does it have to the users? What would fail?

Answer (score 4):

What happens if you don't make the change? Is there value to the user in preventing that from happening? If the answer is yes, I'd recommend tying your business value statement to that. Then, you can write a typical user story with business value and treat it like any other PBI.

Comment: If we don't update the format we won't be able to keep our customer's records updated as the TXT format will be discontinued. I should have said that in the question, but this is somewhat a core function in our system.

Comment: Than this is the answer. The business value is, that the software could be used in the future.

Answer (score -1):

We typically just add it as a "technical improvement" and give it a priority that we think fits. If the user asks you about it, you just explain them high level what the change does and why it's needed.

Don't forget that your application will most likely start failing in the future if you don't make the change. Just tell them that, and let them decide whether they want that or not.

Comment: Although I agree with you that in the end we need to update the parsing engine so the system keeps working, I'm trying to stay inside scrum boundaries and identify a story that adds value to the users and not just from a technical point of view.

Comment: Isn't there an obvious added value : the system keeps working. If you don't do this story, the system stops working, ...

Comment: I would down voted (not enough rep), as teams adding "technical improvements" violates the accountability of the product backlog by the Product Owner.  If the PO, sees no value in "changing the XML format", then it should not be done.  The team need to learn to respect the PO, and the PO needs to learn to respect the team.

Comment: But in this case, you can obviously clearly explain that the XML format needs to adapt to what the party you're working with is going to change it to. Not changing the XML format will break the application.